# I want to pass my android classes data to one class

Tags: android

I have 4 classes that show me the Sensor values and Sound, I get different values in 4 classes using onSensorChanged() and onProgressUpdate(), I want to get these values by clicking one button in my main class

My problem is how can i pass the sensor values to my class?

These is my sound.class

```
        public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while(rec == true){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(250);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ampitude = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
            db =(float) (20 * Math.log10(ampitude));
            publishProgress(db);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void onProgressUpdate(Float... progress){

        database.addSoundData(dB);
        dB = (progress[0].toString());
        sound.setText("dB: "+ dB);
    }
}
```

This is one of my Sensor class

```
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float speedX=event.values[0];
    float speedY=event.values[1];
    float speedZ=event.values[2];
    float absoluteSpeed = (float)Math.sqrt(speedX*speedX + speedY*speedY + speedZ*speedZ);


    db.addSpeedData(speedX, speedY, speedZ, absoluteSpeed );
    String results = "X: "+ event.values[0] + "\nY: "+ event.values[1] + "\nZ: "+ event.values[2] +"\nAbsolute: "+ absoluteSpeed;
    speed.setText(results);

}
```

Comment: If you have all the values available at any time what is the problem then?

Comment: @Laurence Nicolaou pass values to the class constructor. If you want to pass values between activities use intents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a listener to pipe the values to my Activity, you'll get a stream of updates but you can update the UI with them on button press. Here's some rough pseudo code.

Create the listener like so

```
public Interface MyListener{

    public void onSensor1Update(Object value);
    public void onSensor2Update(Object value);
    public void onSensor3Update(Object value);
}
```

Implement it in your Activity and give a reference of your Activity to the sensor classes to act as a listener.

```
public class MyClassActivity implements MyListener{

    public void createSensors(){
        Sensor1 s1 = new Sensor1();
        s1.listener = this;

        Sensor2 s2 = new Sensor2();
        s2.listener = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensor1Update(Object value){
         //do something
    }
    public void onSensor2Update(Object value){
        //do something 
    }
    ....
    ....
    etc.
}
```

Do something like this for each of the classes you want a value for, it can be done for the AsyncTask class too.

```
public class Sensor1{

    public MyListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(...){
        listener.onSensor1Update(some value);
    }

}
```